# Adding check constraint for type double precision in postgres

Tags: postgresql, char, string-length, double-precision

I have coordinates with the type double precision in a column. I want to check the length (it has to be 7) before the decimal point (before the decimal places). The numbers can have decimals up to 4.

My first idea:

```
CHECK (char_length(point_gauss::double precision::char)=...
```

Comment: There is no "length" of floating point values (or variables). What is the "length" of (1/3) ?

Comment: Ok. Is it better to choose the decimal type? In my case `decimal(11,4)`.

Comment: That will depend on what the variable is supposed to represent.

Comment: I have Gauss-Krueger coordinates. I want to avoid that you can insert wrong values. Like coordinates with 6 numbers before the decimal point. Because of that I want to check the "length".

Comment: To me it appears that floating point is sufficiently precise for coordiante systems. Why not just add a range constraint, like  `(value >= -90.0 AND value <=90.0)` ? (you could even pu that into a domain or a type)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think, checking the value here is the most proper way.

Comment: You should also take a look at GIS impletations, such as postgis, which has facilities for every kind of coordinate system that's ever been made. Plus the associated transformations. And functions and operations, such as distance and intersection.

Comment: I've integrated postgis functions in my database,already! I've created a function, which creates point features from the coordinates in my database in a given CRS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For floating point keep in mind these are binary floating point types and so decimal precision is a bit of a problematic concept.  Your first instinct should be something like:

```
 CHECK(point_gauss BETWEEN -9999.999 AND 9999.999)
```

However, if you need specific base 10 precision the best way is to change from double to numeric and use this instead:

```
 point_gauss NUMERIC(7,3),....
```